# Meaning of struct.pack( ) arguments in code for Beagleboard IP assignment

Tags: python, linux, networking, beagleboneblack, struct.pack

I was writing a program to assign IP address to beaglebone black in python using `ioctl`.

(reference [How to assign IP address to interface in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420937/how-to-assign-ip-address-to-interface-in-python) and [Getting IP address of the beagleboard using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726213/getting-ip-address-of-the-beagleboard-using-python) )

Since `IOCTL` method implemented in Linux Kernel needs all the parameters to be passed into a particular structure. Hence I constructed all those parameters as a struct and then passed to `IOCTL`.

```
bin_ip = socket.inet_aton('192.168.0.1')
ifreq = struct.pack('16sH2s4s8s', 'eth0', socket.AF_INET, '\x00'*2, bin_ip, '\x00'*8)
```

found partial meaning of first argument at https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/struct.html as  `s= char[] and H = unsigned short` what is meaning of numbers 16 2 4 8 written with `s` and `H`

edit: For the 's' format character, the count is interpreted as the length of the bytes, for example, `16s` means a single `16-byte string` followed by `1 unsigned short`, `2-byte string` ,`4-byte string` , `8-byte string`

why 4th argument is `'\x00\x00'`and last argument is `'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`? Is this the standard format / expected format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the struct being packed here is [ifreq](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html), where the fields "ifr_name" and "ifr_addr" gets set. 'eth0' gets set for "ifr_name", while the rest is for "ifr_addr".

Ifr_addr is a sockaddr, in this case I suppose actually a sockaddr_in. Based on [this page](http://www.retran.com/beej/sockaddr_inman.html) the fields are:

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    short            sin_family;   // e.g. AF_INET, AF_INET6
    unsigned short   sin_port;     // e.g. htons(3490)
    struct in_addr   sin_addr;     // see struct in_addr, below
    char             sin_zero[8];  // zero this if you want to
};
```

In your code socket.AF_INET sets the sin_family. Then the fourth argument two zeroes are the port, likely as here the IP address is set so it isn't port-specific. Then comes the ip address and finally eight zeroes.

Comment: Thank you . Helped me a lot to clear up my concepts.